# overflow hidden on a Paragraph in Reportlab

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab, platypus

I have a `Table` with 2 cells, inside of each one there is a `Paragraph`

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

table_style_footer = TableStyle(
            [
                ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
                ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, (0, 0, 0)),
                ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
            ]
        )

style_p_footer = ParagraphStyle('Normal')
style_p_footer.fontName = 'Arial'
style_p_footer.fontSize = 8
style_p_footer.leading = 10

Table([
       [
        Paragraph('Send To:', style_p_footer), 
        Paragraph('Here should be a variable with long content', style_p_footer)
       ]
      ],
      [1.7 * cm, 4.8 * cm],
      style=table_style_footer
     )
```

I need hide the overflow content of paragraph , but the paragraph instead of hide the overflow content does a break line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reportlab doesn't seem to have a native support for hiding overflow, but we can achieve it by utilizing the `breakLines` function of a `Paragraph`. The `breakLines` functions returns an object that contains all the lines of the paragraph given a certain width, thus we can also use it to find the first line and discard everything else.

Basically we need to do the following:

1. Create a dummy paragraph
2. Fetch the lines of the dummy
3. Create a the actual paragraph based on the first line of the dummy

Doing this in code looks like this:

```
# Create a dummy paragraph to see how it would split
long_string = 'Here should be a variable with long content'*10
long_paragraph = Paragraph(long_string, style_p_footer)

# Needed because of a bug in breakLines (value doesn't matter)
long_paragraph.width = 4.8 * cm

# Fetch the lines of the paragraph for the given width
para_fragment = long_paragraph.breakLines(width=4.8 * cm)

# There are 2 kinds of returns so 2 ways to grab the first line
if para_fragment.kind == 0:
    shorted_text = " ".join(para_fragment.lines[0][1])
else:
    shorted_text = " ".join([w.text for w in para_fragment.lines[0].words])

# To make it pretty add ... when we break of the sentence
if len(para_fragment.lines) > 1:
    shorted_text += "..."

# Create the actual paragraph
shorted_paragraph = Paragraph(shorted_text, style_p_footer)
```

Comment: Works perfect. I have a question, How can I do `para_fragment.kind` to be different from `0`? @B8vrede

Comment: Adding a inline pagebreak will cause it to become kind 1 :)

Comment: "Adding a inline pagebreak" like \n? :D

Comment: No the HTML kind which is almost impossible to typ on a phone while standing in a supermarket :p

Comment: XD... something like <para>Some long text </br> Some another long text </para>

Comment: `<BR />` was the one I meant :)